# Changing int main() to JNI interface prototype

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I changed `ffmpeg.c` according following link:

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-port-ffmpeg-the-program-to-androidideas-and-thoughts/

He said the change `main ()` to JNI interface prototype. Well, I'm not familiar with JNI interface prototype, but I read an article about JNI and change it accordingly.

Can anyone look at my code to see is this true or not?

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ffmpegtest_MainActivity_main(JNIEnv *pEnv, int argc, char **argv) {
int64_t ti;

av_log_set_flags(AV_LOG_SKIP_REPEATED);

if(argc>1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-d")){
run_as_daemon=1;
verbose=-1;
av_log_set_callback(log_callback_null);
argc--;
argv++;

}

avcodec_register_all();
#if CONFIG_AVDEVICE
avdevice_register_all();
#endif
#if CONFIG_AVFILTER
avfilter_register_all();
#endif
av_register_all();

#if HAVE_ISATTY
if(isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
avio_set_interrupt_cb(decode_interrupt_cb);
#endif

init_opts();

if(verbose>=0)
show_banner();

/* parse options */
parse_options(argc, argv, options, opt_output_file);

if(nb_output_files <= 0 && nb_input_files == 0) {
show_usage();
fprintf(stderr, "Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'\n");
ffmpeg_exit(1);
}

/* file converter / grab */
if (nb_output_files <= 0) {
fprintf(stderr, "At least one output file must be specified\n");
ffmpeg_exit(1);
}

if (nb_input_files == 0) {
fprintf(stderr, "At least one input file must be specified\n");
ffmpeg_exit(1);
}

ti = getutime();
if (transcode(output_files, nb_output_files, input_files, nb_input_files,
stream_maps, nb_stream_maps) < 0)
ffmpeg_exit(1);
ti = getutime() - ti;
if (do_benchmark) {
int maxrss = getmaxrss() / 1024;
printf("bench: utime=%0.3fs maxrss=%ikB\n", ti / 1000000.0, maxrss);
}

return ffmpeg_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
Java_com_ffmpegtest_MainActivity_main(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject obj) {
```

where `obj` is the object of which this function is a member, i.e. your `MainActivity` instance. If you need to pass extra arguments, you'll need to add them to the native method declaration in the Java code as well.

Comment: No. If you need more elaboration on specific points, then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused about the use of obj.

Comment: `obj` is the `MainActivity` object which contains your `main` method.

Comment: I got another problem , when I try to compile the code , compiler give me an error : no previous prototype for 'Java_com_ffmpegtest_MainActivity_main'

Comment: @iSun change the declaration in the header file too, or regenerate it with javah.